# What is Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse?

Tags: android

When I was continuing a course from a known academy, I found this TODO in this course:

```
<!-- TODO (1) Create a style that shows a Sunshine logo instead of a title -->
```

well, it is solved in their answer for exercise:

```
<!-- COMPLETED (2) Create a style for MainActivity called AppTheme.Forecast that uses our custom ActionBar style -->
<style name="AppTheme.Forecast" parent="@style/AppTheme">
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar.Solid.Sunshine.NoTitle</item>
</style>.
```

when I followed definition of

```
@style/ActionBar.Solid.Sunshine.NoTitle
```

I found

```
<style name="ActionBar.Solid.Sunshine.NoTitle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
```

I didn't understand this answer, what is the meaning of

```
Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse
```

and why they used it.

What if I didn't find the solution ?

What is the documentation for themes ?

Comment: I think you are searching for something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41580441/how-can-i-theme-my-action-bar-to-match-this-image
But before that, You should read about the core of android styling from below links:-
1. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/themes
2. https://guides.codepath.com/android/using-the-app-toolbar

Comment: Well, you guided me to the way I can style the Action Bar, but I want to proceed the ability to manipulate design based on built in Android framework theme using whatever such as documentation

Comment: Well in that case, Let's say you have a dark theme. `colorPrimary` will be a light color so you can see it against the dark background. But maybe you have a card view that you really want to stand out, so in your dark theme this card view gets a light background to contrast against the dark container background. In this case, you might style the text with `colorPrimaryInverse` (a dark color) so you can see it on the light `cardview` or `toolbar` you are using.

Comment: Yes, I mean what is the reference for these issues to depend on it in case such as ours ?

Comment: When I want to use one of android built in themes, how can I use it ? based on documentation or based on trying every theme or how

Comment: You can simply check your product requirements and decide what themes to use by googling about `style` and `theme` you want to use. For example: You want to develop a product with `Day Mode` and `Night Mode` theme, in which user can switch between themes, so that you have to keep two different themes (i.e: `AppTheme.Day` and `AppTheme.Night`) inside your app and when user switches the theme to `Night Mode` then your app should be updated with the `AppTheme.Night` or the `Dark Mode` and vice-versa. Hope you get it.